# File is not being created (csv)

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I want to print data to a csv file, I am using this code, and I think everything is alright with the code, however the file isnt created.

```php
$headers = array("name", "website");
$data = array(
  array(
    "name" => "john morris",
    "website" => "google.com",
  ),
  array(
    "name" => "Alan Gustav",
    "website" => "github.org",
  ),
);

$fh = fopen("file.csv", "w");

fputcsv($fh, $headers);
foreach($data as $fields){
  fputcsv($fh, $fields);
}
fclose($fh);
```

I am using ubuntu and have permissions set to write, read and execute on this folders, also this folders and files are in a ntfs partition.

Any idea why is the file.csv not being created?

update:  was the path on the fopen, a full path already works properlly.  Thanks all.!

Comment: Is your question tagged correctly? It looks like your problem is file creation from a shell script, not the CSV format itself.

Comment: I'm not a PHP guy, but two things come into my mind: 1) Did you try creating a simple text file for testing? Does this work? 2) Did you check what your current working directory is?  Ie the file might be created, but not where you expect it ... You can try printing the result of [`getcwd()`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.getcwd.php) to the console to see your current working directory.

Comment: Try using an absolute path for the filename, to ensure it's put where you expect.

Comment: Take a look at the server error log to be sure you're not encountering an unforeseen error.

Comment: was the path, an absolute path and it is already working, kudos for Barmar